# How to perform a Select ALL statement with some operation on one column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know how to make a Select All except for one column which will have some operation on it like for example doing substr.  I do not want to manually select each field one by one or do Minus then Union.

Example:

```
Select *, substr(fieldXYZ,0,5) from myTable;
```

This of course does not work.
It will be more convenient in case there are say 100 columns.

Comment: It is impossible. You can create view and list all the needed columns there. After that just use the view instead of the table.

Comment: Don't be lazy, specify columns! (select * is for ad-hoc queries only, don't use it when programming.)

Comment: Okay good, thanks sidux.

Comment: It's columns, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
select myTable.*, substr(fieldXYZ, 0, 5) from myTable
```

or

```
select t.*, substr(t.fieldXYZ, 0, 5) from myTable t
```

Comment: in what way does it "not seem to work". How is anyone supposed to help you if you don't supply specifics, given that we're not standing over your shoulder and can't see what's on your screen!

Comment: The result of doing 'select myTable.*, substr(fieldXYZ, 0, 5) from myTable' is the same as 'select * from myTable'

Comment: If it is not possible, then i will just stick to the traditional way. thnks for ur help :)